# Decode the value based on condition in Oracle pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables **test1** and **test2**.

In `test1`, there are columns called `rec_id` and `deptno`. `deptno` has values `10,20,30,40....`

In `test2` table, column `rec_id` and `deptno` are also available.

I need conditional output for `deptno` `30` based on the availability of this value in `test2` table.

```
rec_id  deptno  decoded value   condition
1           10              a          NA
2           20              b          NA
3           30   c or discard
```

If `rec_id` = `3` and `deptno` = `30` is available in `test2` table, then discard, else `C`:

```
4           40              d          NA
5           50              f          NA
```

I don't want to create any function for this issue because its a context switch between sql and pl/sql engine and impact the performance.

Please let me know the better way to do this using simple sql.many thanks!

I have used decode like this:

```
select decode(test1.deptno,
              10, 'a',
              20, 'b',
              30, 'required ur help',
              40, 'd',
              50, 'e') from test1;
```

Comment: You are encoding your condition in your table? This isn't quite clear.

Comment: decode() is logically equivalent to a case construct but much less readable.  That makes case constructs better, in my opinion.

Comment: i just display the value based on the data available in test2 table,if deptno 30 with re_id 3 available in table test2 then i want to select discard message for this else C.decode(deptno,if 30 and not exist in table test2,'C','DISCARD') from table test1..how an i achive this.please suggest

Comment: Please provide a clear definition (preferably with insert statements) for `test1`, `test2` and the expected output.

Comment: I would add that a function probably won't impact the performance - in fact that's a premature optimization.  The use of PL/SQL functions/packages are encouraged since they are already compiled into bytecode - it will run quicker vs the cost for Oracle parse the code. Finally, assuming you name your function well, I think it would also improve readability.

Comment: insert into test1 values(1,10);insert into test1 values(2,20);insert into test1 values(3,30);insert into test1 values(4,40);insert into test1 values(5,50);                                                                                                                                     test2 table insert:                                                                      insert into test2 values(3,30);insert into test2 values(4,30);insert into test2 values(2,20);

Answer (score 1):

IF you want to return different values then this is how you do it.

```
select decode(test1.deptno,
              10, 'a',
              20, 'b',
              30, decode((select count(*)
                          from test2 b
                          where b.rec_id=3
                            and b.deptno = 30)
                         ,0,'c'
                         ,'discard')
              40, 'd',
              50,'e') from test1 a;
```

If by "discard" you mean "not return this row" then you just use NOT EXISTS like this

```
select decode(test1.deptno,
              10, 'a',
              20, 'b',
              30, 'c',
              40, 'd',
              50,'e') from test1 a
where not exists (select 1
                  from test2 b
                  where b.rec_id = 3
                    and b.deptno = 30
                    and b.rec_id = a.rec_id
                    and b.deptno = a.deptno);
```